# Why is the Christian god being spelled with a lowercase letter?

Tags: orthography

It's been going on for some time, but the phenomenon which was once seen as almost an act of *rebellion* is now becoming more commonplace. God, capitalized, is increasingly seen only at the start of a sentence. Leaving aside whether one believes in a god, or in the Christian God Himself, why is this convention not being criticized?

God is after all a proper noun, the name of a deity which for over 2,000 years we have all heard of, and know by that very name. It matters not that *god* or *God* may or may not exist. It is a name. And like any other name that belongs to a real person or a fictional character in a book, it ought to be spelled with a capital letter.

I always feel uncomfortable writing about God with a capital letter, I always feel there is a hoard of die-hard atheists ready to accuse me of being a creationist, god forbid. (Should that have been: "..., God forbid"?)

Is the spelling of the Christian "God" politically incorrect?  Is God with a capital letter, grammatically speaking, an archaic tradition? And if so, why?

**EDIT**: From the answers so far posted, no one has yet mentioned the political and social consequences this deceptively innocent, lowercase spelling may have had on us, on today's society. And this has lead me wondering, whether in the history of the English language there has been anything similar; any linguistic *subversion*, spoken or written which was in reality a show of defiance toward an established authority such as a government or political leader.

Comment: If you're going to ask about the Christian God, could you use capital letters in the question title?

Comment: It was a provocation, I admit. It looks odd to my eyes, and if I capitalize Christian God, in the title, I think my argument weakens.

Comment: You could legitmately ask "Why is the christian god spelled with uppercase letters?" and cast the question from the other point of view.

Comment: @AtsutoNagatomo Ngram, as far as I am aware, Ngram graphs are based on books. There are many hundreds of evangelical books being published continually. My observation is based on real life, on what I read and observe, especially on the Internet.

Comment: @AndrewLeach the problem with your second suggestion, is I know the answer to that question, and it has been asked before on ELU. If you could suggest another way around, or convince me that my question won't be put on hold because it is a duplicate. I'll change the title. I want to avoid confusion, and contradictions.

Comment: When I see ***God*** I also expect whoever wrote it to capitalise ***Him***. I never do so myself for the exact opposite reasons

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is just due to lazy writers. Lots of words are losing their capital letters as people don't bother hitting the shift key unless they _really_ need to. Do you have evidence that this phenomenon is increasing in frequency? I certainly don't recall reading a piece of formal writing, not written by an atheist making a point about religion, where God is intentionally not capitalized where it would otherwise be. It is, as you say, a proper name or title which should be capitalized at least for disambiguation.

Comment: This is not only a case of laziness, which is a contributing factor, but also a form of statement. By writing *god* they are making the point they are atheists. It is a type of code, and it's very common in forums. Much less so in newspaper articles, I would have to do some research. I doubt the spelling convention exists in any printed book; but I could check up on Christopher Hitchens and Richard Dawkin's books. I highly doubt it, though.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 On page 64, "Augustine was a self-centred fantasist an earth-centred ignoramus: he was guiltily convinced that god cared about his trivial theft from some unimportant pear trees...." page 67, " ...such as Nietzche's histrionic and self-contradictory pronouncement that god was dead." From the book GOD IS NOT GREAT by Christopher Hitchens. When Hitchens writes God with a capital letter it is always within quotation marks.

Comment: I'm not convinced that only atheists don't capitalize "god" but maybe also the less devout.  I agree that it's a statement by *that writer* to communicate the degree of importance they assign to the deity.

Comment: Political and social consequences?  Really?  It seems like a fairly small detail to me.

Comment: @snailboat  A small detail perhaps, but I believe it is a significant one. The world is changing, and this is reflected in our speech and in our writing.

Comment: @snailboat  But you do care about your language. How you write and express your ideas and thoughts matters to you, and it matters that you follow the conventions of style, syntax the silent, internalized rules which dictate to you, whether a phrase is grammatical or not. Thus it should matter if a proper noun is capitalized or not. If it doesn't matter, then you should be coherent and not capitalize any names, any proper nouns. Any way, I am not looking for a fight. The small phenomenon of God being spelled with a lowercase letter has always intrigued me for years.

Comment: I think you have to demonstrate a lot more solid evidence for your claims before I will feel that this question isn't just peeving. Show me the data that demonstrates that the Christian 'God' is trending to 'god', and then show me the data that demonstrates that this is some kind of atheist plot against Christians. And lastly, if you know the reasons why it is spelled with a capital letter, then you know the reasons you ought not care if a hoard of die-hard atheists pounces on you for being orthographically correct.

Comment: @KitFox I cannot show you the data that there is a trend. I doubt if such a data exists, but are you denying that it happens?  You are right about one thing, I shouldn't care if total strangers, atheists or non, pounce on me for expressing an idea, an opinion about wider issues other than how a word is spelled (or *spelt*, finally! I get to write "spelt" I've been holding back for 13 hours now.) :)

Comment: 1) I don't think the phenomenon exists. 2) I don't see how you can show it except by laborious text research 3) Even if it does exist you're asking for an explanation, which is obvious (making lowercase makes it not a proper noun) 4) that phenomenon happens all the time with proper names used as generics: Kleenex-> kleenex, Google-> google.

Comment: Which is all to say that your explicit questions "Is the spelling of the Christian "God" politically incorrect? Is God with a capital letter, grammatically speaking, an archaic tradition? And if so, why?" are not about English language and orthography but about..those topics. There might be a reasonable answer better found at christianity.SE.

Comment: @Mitch I paid a visit or two at the Christianity.SE site and it wasn't for me. I was curious to know if anybody else on ELU had noted this decline and what they thought about it. The capitalization of the pronouns; Him, He and Himself was standard usage even in non-religious texts. Today that usage is becoming increasingly rarer. These points I consider belonging pertinently to English Language and Usage, I thought it might have started an interesting discussion. My fault, I phrased and presented my question poorly. It happens.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Oh. Well, then maybe a rewording about the trend might make this re-openable. Now that you mention it, it is very noticeable when Him and He  are used, which makes me think they may not be used as much any more. But that's not the same as 'God'.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Hitchens was an atheist making a point about religion. I admit that in those circles there is definitely a tendency to use lowercase letters where Christians feel that respect demands uppercase letters.

Comment: @Mitch Please, if you believe the question can be opened by rewording it, feel free to edit. As for the declining custom to capitalize the pronouns related to God, isn't that a consequence of using the lowercase letter g? The growing number of (ex)Christians who are either atheists or class themselves as being spiritual reflect the tendency to regard God as just being a god among many different deities.

Comment: Speculatively speaking, I'd say this *trend* first began in the UK; and became noticeable in the late 80s. (The US has a far higher percent of practising Christians and Protestants which might explain why some users on ELU contested that such a phenomenon existed).

Comment: @Mari-LouA: "if you believe the question can be opened by rewording it, feel free to edit." What? It's _your_ question! You're the one who knows what you want.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: "As for...the pronouns related to God, isn't that a consequence of using the lowercase letter g?" Maybe but you asked about 'God' in  particular, not about pronouns, which happen to be different things. Also, you didn't mention pronouns, so how would we know to answer about that?

Comment: @Mitch  I was suggesting that someone like yourself could do a better job, it sounded you were interested. My mistake. I realize the question is/was unpopular, the down votes is proof enough but I do *know* one thing, it is not a duplicate. My question is quite a bit different from the one proposed by the community. I do not want to get into a discussion over this. I accept the community's decision.

Comment: In reply to your observation that I did not ask about using capitalizing pronouns, that's true. I hadn't thought about it until I read somebody's comment or answer, I forget whose. But it's often the case that answers to a question can reveal aspects of the language that we may have overlooked, taken for granted or perhaps we had forgotten about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are more than a few cases that complicate the use of the words *god* and *God*.

The most obvious is that *God* is a proper noun used to name a particular god, and this leaves some possible difference as in:

> Oh my God!
>
> Oh my god!

Even if we were extremely strict to the use of capitals for *God* as a name, and assume the speaker is Christian (though if anything such exclamations should not be made by Christians in most contexts where they are heard), we could still consider either correct, the former addressing their god by name, the latter referring to Him by what He is.

Another issue is that *god* and *God* are used as a proper noun not just for the Christian god*, but for a variety of monotheistic concepts, including pantheism, deism, Neoplatonism and other concepts that combine monotheism and polytheism (consider the popularity in neopagan circles of Dion Fortune's forumla "All gods are one God, and all goddesses are one Goddess, and there is one Initiator"), and perhaps in particular in cases where one is deliberately quite vague and covering all such concepts. There are also translations from Eastern religion that use *god* or *God* with differing degrees with how well one could argue them relevant.

Now, here we may still use *God* with a captial as in the Fortune quote above (though Fortune was herself a Christian for all her unorthodoxy and would be inclined to mirror the conventions among them when not explicitly moving away from one for a reason). We might also though, use a non-captial form, as capitals are not always used with proper nouns (consider that when "history" is used as a proper noun as in "for all of history" it is normally not capitalised). This makes the form *god* also appropriate, especially the further we move from any precise view on which god is referred to, or in those cases in which the god believed in is not (or not necessarily) believed to be a person or persons in the same way that some religious views hold their god to be, making the capital form less applicable.

Now, if I say "god does not play dice" or "God does not play dice", which god do I refer to? Am I referring to the Judeo-Christian god because the man I am quoting was from a Jewish background, or am I being vauger since the phrase is after all figurative?

The answer in Western society is that it's somewhere between the two: We have a lot of different concepts of *god* and *God* both literal and figurative within our society, and we also have a strong influence of Christianity as the strongest religious influence in the English-speaking world for many centuries (with Judaism being the second strongest), but not the sole view; consider in particular the importance of Deism among Enlightenment thinkers whose influence on scientific, artistic and political thought persist to this day.

Some of this has been explicitly suggested too, mostly as justifications for religious intrusion into all manner of secular aspects of life with a claim that references to *god* do not necessarily refer to *God*.

Some of this is more implicit, when people of different beliefs - which may in themselves be quite vauge - speak in vague terms to each other.

So, it's quite sensible that we should end up with *god* and *God* both being used for the vaguely probably-Christian-but-perhaps-not-quite concept of divinity that is most often addressed.

And that's before we get to the fact that many people just simply won't care.

*Note that this is another point where I could validly use either, "the Christian god" meaning the god that Christians have and "the Christian God" meaning the god that the Christians have, who they refer to as *God*.

Comment: I planned to edit this to do so, and then undelete, but I haven't had time and won't today either, so I'm just undeleting.

Comment: Thank you so much for undeleting your thoughtful and well argued answer, it would have been a *sin* if you had kept it hidden. :)

Answer (score 6):

It's not uncommon to see *god* used to many any (hypothetical, even) god, but *God* for the Christian deity. It's not always clear whether the writer and the reader are referring to the same god, it's perfectly possible that the writer is using a phrase like "for god's sake", while not believing in God.

**Added after clarification of question:**

Between the two extremes there is a large area of personal opinion and style. I would never write *the father, the son (jesus), and the holy spirit; "one god in three persons" [(wikipedia:Trinity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity)* (except that I just did for sake of a example).  But I would be unlikely to write something like *people who believe in a God, any God* either.  Phrases like "God forbid", etc. fall, for me, into this grey area.  Then there are cross-cultural examples - I've heard "Oh gods, you wouldn't want to go the Delhi in the monsoon" - the phrase derived from the Christian god, the usage clearly modified.

There will always be militant atheists, and militant supporters of any religion, it's much easier to offend both at once than to offend neither.  Don't forget that much of what's been said in this discussion would have been regarded as blasphemy in the past.

And there always *christian* vs. *Christian* as well!

Answer (score 6):

I offer up this small point - I do not consider God to be a name, but a title, as in Sir or Queen, so in theory, it should be capitalized. I was raised Christian, but am, like many in the UK these days, not conventionally religious any more. I still, though, capitalize God if I'm referring to the Christian God directly, for differentiation purposes, but never at any other time, so 'oh my god' would be lower case. As for Jesus (quoted in ChrisH's answer), that is a name, and I always capitalize it.

UPDATE:
Chris, my theory regarding God being a title is personal to me, it just seems logical. There have been many gods down the centuries, after all.

Regarding subversion and general rebellion (in the edited Question), there is a long tradition in the UK of this down the centuries. Lampoons, cartoons, printed pamphlets, newspapers, all of it, though I'm sure that's a worldwide practice wherever possible. But I don't believe the non capitalization of the Christian 'God' is a subversive or rebellious act. I'm sure it's come about because of the increasing secularity of society, particularly in the UK, compared to, say, 100 years ago. If 'God' is a meaningless concept to someone, I doubt they'll bother to capitalize the word, it's not important enough, or they may have other gods of their own. In other words, it's not a deliberate subversion which will have a dramatic effect on society, it's the other way around; a symptom of secularity. Curiously, though, I've never yet observed Jesus being spelt without the capital letter, even amongst non believers, which speaks to my theory about god being a title rather than a name. Although it's probably fair to say that non believers don't very often have cause to write Jesus in anything anyway.

I'll add here from my Comment - that any follower of a monotheistic religion will always capitalize the name of whichever god they worship.

Comment: But if this is why it's capitalized, then why do people write *His* or *Him*?  I'm not saying your answer is wrong, but I'm not sure it tells the whole story.

Comment: Well, if you are a practising Christian, then both pronouns would be capitalized. As would Her...which is no less likely than Him, logically. But I'm sure anyone practising a monotheistic religion always capitalizes anything referring to their particular god.

Comment: My example - as I suspect you knew - was an extreme one, but the distinction between title and name is not clear as it would be for people.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I've lost all patience with the militant atheists.  I capitalize "god" according to how the usage best indicates and if someone gets offended, well, that is their problem, not mine.  I don't deliberately seek to torque people off, but if I were to try to avoid all offense at all times, then I would be silent.  Which, to some people, at least, would be a dearly-to-be-hoped-for outcome, but nevermind.

@bamboo is correct, "god" is not a proper name, for all that people treat it like one.  The Hebrew and Christian god declined to be identified by name as a matter of general policy, so the generic term "god" came in as a way to refer to him, or even to talk to him, and in substitution for a name it became the custom to capitalize it, as if it were a name.

As to militant atheists, my very favorite is Pat Condell.  He is a Brit, a former  standup comedian (or perhaps he's still active in comedy, I'm not sure).  He holds forth regularly on YouTube under his own name, so if you're interested you can check him out.  His rants are almost always worth listening to, even if they are sometimes irritating to a theist.

I suppose it might be useful to point out that I am definitely a theist and a Christian, and a practicing one as well (and will continue to practice until I get it right).

**Edited to Add:** In response to the edit of the question, I have to say I have no knowledge of any historical capitalization wars with regard to names of Deity.

Comment: 'bamboo is correct, "god" is not a proper name, for all that people treat it like one.' One could argue that 'treating a word as a proper noun' makes it one. In most cases, there is a strong element of user-definition in the words we use. However, I agree that here the usual factors informing insertion into a word (sub-)class - notional, syntactic/distributional, formal - may be trumped.